# C# Linq how to add each missing year and month to data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of the following class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

With the date range given by the user, I am bringing data on year and month basis. However there is no data for some year and month in the given date range.

```
var dateRange = new List<DateTime>();

for (DateTime date = Report.Parameter.BeginDate; date <= Report.Parameter.EndDate; date.AddMonths(1))
{
    dateRange.Add(new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1));
}
```

For each year and month in the given date range, I want the Data object to come with a Amount column of 0 (zero).

This data should be added once for each Sector, Company, Branch and Category columns.

Example:
[image: screen shot]

How do I do this with linq?

Comment: `How do i do it with linq`, i think you should explore how you might do it without linq first, Then maybe when you understand the nature of what you are trying to do, you'll figure out how you may or may not be able to do it another way

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs. _As is, I am struggling to understand what you expect to happen. A [mcve] will help me understand what you want._

Comment: `DateTime` is immutable. By running `date.AddMonths(1)` you're not really mutating the `date` instance. Try `date = date.AddMonths(1)` instead...

Comment: One solution is to generate a collection of all  year and months for your range. Then with a clever `foreach` and `select` you can create the list your are looking for.

Comment: When I try to accomplish something with linq I do it first by creating the code with for-loops and foreach-loops and if the code works, I try to shorten the code with linq. If you are new to linq you can try LINQPad. Its a tool where you can test small linq statements.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, 12).Select(x => mydate.AddMonths(x));` you can create date range using this

Comment: Linq is not always the answer, its not it cant be done but more performant code can lie outside linq.

Comment: You can use `Enumerable.Range` to create the date range, and then do a left join to combine the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use Linq, it would look like this:

```
    public void MyFunction(List<Data> userData)
    {
        var beginDate = DateTime.Today;
        var endDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(2);
        var monthsApart = 12 * (beginDate.Year - endDate.Year) + beginDate.Month - endDate.Month;
        var dateRange = Enumerable.Range(0, monthsApart).Select(offset => beginDate.AddMonths(offset));

        var difference = dateRange.Where(item => !(userData.Any(uData => uData.Year == item.Year && uData.Month == item.Month)));
        userData.AddRange(difference.Select(date => new Data() {Year = date.Year, Month = date.Month, Amount = 0}));
    }
```

This is just an example. You need to add your logic, where it is needed.

You mentioned `This data should be added once for each Sector, Company, Branch and Category columns`
If you want to do this, you have to call

```
        userData.AddRange(difference.Select(date => new Data() {Year = date.Year, Month = date.Month, Amount = 0}));
```

as many times as you have combinations of Sector, Company, Branch and Category.

I hope this helps to understand and my explanation is not too complex.